# Using substitute() to get argument names, multiple levels up

Tags: r

Consider this function `a()`, which prints out the argument that was passed in:

```
a <- function(x) {
  message("The input is ", deparse(substitute(x)))
}

a("foo")
# The input is "foo"

tmplist <- list(x1 = 1, x2=2)
a(tmplist)
# The input is tmplist
```

That works. But when `a()` is called from another function, it no longer prints out the original argument names:

```
b <- function(y) {
  a(y)
}

b("foo")
# The input is y

b(tmplist)
# The input is y
```

One solution that seems to work is to wrap in another `substitute` and an `eval`:

```
a1 <- function(x) {
  message("The input is ", deparse(eval(substitute(substitute(x)), parent.frame())))
}

a1("foo")
# The input is "foo"

tmplist <- list(x1 = 1, x2=2)
a1(tmplist)
# The input is tmplist

b1 <- function(y) {
  a1(y)
}

b1("foo")
# The input is "foo"

b1(tmplist)
# The input is tmplist
```

But this seems inelegant. And it fails if I add another layer:

```
c1 <- function(z) {
  b1(z)
}
c1("foo")
# The input is z
```

Is there a good, general way to get the original argument?

Comment: I'm no expert on handling environments, but I think either playing with `parent.frame` as kohske did, or specifying a global variable are  your only choices.  R does not pass by reference the way c does.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it this will work well in all situations, but try this:

```
f0 <- function(x) {
  nn <- substitute(x)
  i <- 1
  while(TRUE) {
    on <- do.call("substitute", list(as.name(nn), parent.frame(i)))
    if (on == nn) break;
    nn <- on
    i <- i + 1
  }
  message("The input is ", nn)
}

f1 <-function(.f1) f0(.f1)
f2 <- function(.f2) f1(.f2)
```

and then,

```
> f2(foo)
The input is foo
> f1(poo)
The input is poo
> f0(moo)
The input is moo
> f2(";(")
The input is ;(
> f1(":)")
The input is :)
> f0(":p")
The input is :p
```

Comment: That's pretty good. But if the name of the variable is the same in two successive steps, then I think that fools it into stopping before it's really finished. Suppose you define f1 and f2 so they take `xx` as the argument -- then it stops there.  Maybe the solution is to keep looping until `i==sys.nframe()`.

Answer (score 3):

Adapting kohske's answer, here is something that works, but doesn't stop going up the frame stack prematurely, if the variable has the same name in two successive frames. I don't know if it work correctly in all situations, but it seems to handle my needs. The quoting of strings vs. variables is a little different from before, but that's OK for my case.

```
a <- function(x) {
  newname <- substitute(x)

  # Travel up the frame stack until we hit the top.
  for(i in seq_len(sys.nframe())) {
    oldname <- do.call("substitute", list(as.name(newname), parent.frame(i)))
    newname <- oldname
  }
  message("The input is ", deparse(newname))
}

b <- function(y)  a(y)

c <- function(z)  b(z)

a("adsf")
# The input is adsf
a(foo)
# The input is foo

b("adsf")
# The input is adsf
b(foo)
# The input is foo

c("adsf")
# The input is adsf
c(foo)
# The input is foo
```

Answer (score 1):

While this is an interesting question in its own right, I wonder if the best solution is just to pass the variable name as a character, ie, in quotes.  Then none of this is necessary.  If the object corresponding to the name is needed, it can then be gotten with `get` or `as.name` and `do.call`, depending on how you're using it within the function.

```
> f0 <- function(x) {message("The input is ", x)}
> f1 <- function(.f1) f0(.f1)
> f2 <- function(.f2) f1(.f2)
> f2("aa")
The input is aa
> f1("bb")
The input is bb
> f0("cc")
The input is cc
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach won't work in my application. I need to pass along the original object. The purpose of all this is just to print out an error message with the names of the input arguments if something goes wrong.

Comment: Hmmmm.... I believe there's a way to "propogate" the error up the chain, so that an error in a called function will trigger a message in the top function, where you do know the variable's "true name."  Someone who's better educated than I in the use of `error` and `trycatch` may be able to jump in here.   Once again, we see the importance of asking the right question!

Comment: @wch: To expand on Carl's last comment, the right question is usually about what you're actually trying to do, not about how you are trying to do it.  That is, not "How do I use X to do Y?" or worse, "How do I do X?"  Instead ask "How do I do Y?  I've tried X, but it's not working."

Answer (score 0):

How about recursively calling your function when

```
deparse(substitute(x))!=deparse(eval(substitute(substitute(x)), parent.frame())
```